# google.visualization.Query does not seem to work on my code anymore

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I am dusting off an old html page I have not used in a few years that pulls data from google sheets.  I had a bunch of them that worked just fine a few year but are not working anymore.

This is the code that is failing in my Javascript:

```
var docfile = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=10LWh5nrLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {sendMethod: 'auto'});
docfile.setQuery('select A, B, C, D, E, F');
docfile.send(handleQueryResponse);
```

When I load the page I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Query')

The spreadsheet is still there with the same `key ID` and nothing has changed there.

Is `google.visualization.Query` not supported anymore?
Is there a new method to reference the data from google sheets?

Comment: How are you including the Google Visualization library? Perhaps you need to [Update Library Loader Code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs) (and because it's a "old html page") you can try to update the `Library Loader Code`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the script from [www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js](http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js) to [www.google.com/jsapi](http://www.google.com/jsapi)

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`